# Java, selenium. Как избавиться от постоянной прокидки драйвера при инициализации страниц и локаторов?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, testng

Пишу авто тесты java selenium возник вопрос, как реализовать WebDriver так, что бы при создании объектов страниц не нужно было постоянно передавать экземпляр драйвера вот так:

`Page page = new Page(driver)`

хотелось бы что бы было так:

`Page page = new Page()`

То же касается и локаторов. Естественно это должно работать при параллельном запуске

Comment: ну сделай singleton, который будет отдаввать тебе драйвер, и везде бери ссылку на этот драйвер. Либо же используй Dependency Injection от какого-нибудь spring'a. А по сути - лучше прокидывай

Comment: Спасибо. Как думаете если я буду выдавать драйвер по идентификатору потока это удачное решение?

Comment: на каждый поток свой драйвер? ну такое себе